# How call invoke-expression to pass arguments when calling a remote script in powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell

My script content:

```
param (
    [string]$arg1 = "2.2.2",
    [string]$arg2 = "master" 
)

& {
Write-Host "show $arg1 and $arg2 .."
}
```

Then I want to call this script in remote machine via http.

```
Invoke-Expression (Invoke-Webrequest "https://x.x.x.x/myscript.ps1" -UseBasicParsing).Content
```

But I don't know how to pass parameters to the script. Like this?

```
Invoke-Expression (Invoke-Webrequest "https://x.x.x.x/myscript.ps1" -UseBasicParsing).Content -arg1 2.2.1 -arg2 dev
```

How can help me? thanks!

---

If I do not pass arguments, the following commands are working fine.

```
Invoke-Expression (Invoke-Webrequest "https://x.x.x.x/myscript.ps1" -UseBasicParsing).Content
```

Comment: *"I want to call this script in remote machine via http."* - Via HTTP? Powershell does not include an HTTP server, you can't call **any** Powershell script via HTTP. For remote script execution, use PSSessions. See this "Scripting Guy" blog post (https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/12/11/use-powershell-to-create-remote-session/) and the documentation of PSSessions on the MSDN.

Comment: @Tomalak not http server. I only want to get ps script from the http url and call it with arguments.

Comment: I believe your question is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54408925/45375) (but cannot me closed as such, due to an open bounty).

Answer (score 1):

Download the code, create a scriptblock from it, and provide the arguments when calling `Invoke()` on the scriptblock.

```
$script = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/gittorta/75838602b2712d49c44e85ea0bc179e9/raw/8392f437943f66d47731423b674b81bd74378e4b/myscript.ps1'
$sb = [scriptblock]::Create($script)
$arg1 = "test1"
$arg2 = "test2"

$sb.Invoke($arg1, $arg2)
```

Output

```
show test1 and test2 ..
```

Same command condensed into a one-liner

```
([scriptblock]::Create((Invoke-RestMethod -Uri 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/gittorta/75838602b2712d49c44e85ea0bc179e9/raw/8392f437943f66d47731423b674b81bd74378e4b/myscript.ps1'))).Invoke("test1", "test2")
```

Comment: Note that the PowerShell-idiomatic way to invoke a script block is to use `& $sb $arg1 $arg2` - I'd stay away from the `.Invoke()` method, not only syntactically, but also because it subtly modifies the invocation semantics with respect to errors. The caveat with respect to this solution is that if the downloaded script contains an `exit` statement, the calling session will exit as a whole. The question at hand should really be closed as a duplicate; I feel that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54410144/45375) discusses the relevant solution options and their pitfalls.

Comment: Always appreciate the sage advice @mklement0!  I agree that the linked answer is a more than adequate answer for this question as well.