# What is shortest possible way to download script from HTTP and run it with parameters using Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I have a PowerShell script file stored in an internal artifact server. The script URL is `http://company-server/bootstrap.ps1`.

What is a concise way to download that script and execute with a custom parameter?

I want to send such a command to users, who will copy-paste it over and over, so it must be a single-line and should be short.

What I currently have works, but it is long and unwieldy:

```
$c=((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('http://company-server/bootstrap.ps1'));Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock ([Scriptblock]::Create($c)) -ArgumentList 'RunJob'
```

I am wondering if there is shorter way to do this.

Comment: `& ([ScriptBlock]::Create((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('http://company-server/bootstrap.ps1'))) RunJob`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<sup>Note: From a [code golf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_golf) perspective, the solutions below could be shortened further, by eliminating insignificant whitespace; e.g.,  `&{$args[0]}hi` instead of  `& { $args[0] } hi`. However, in the interest of readability such whitespace was kept.</sup>

A short formulation of a **command that downloads a script via HTTP and executes it locally, optionally with arguments** is probably this, taking advantage of:

- alias `irm` for `Invoke-RestMethod`, in lieu of `(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString()`
- omitting quoting where it isn't necessary
- relying on positional parameter binding

```bash
& ([scriptblock]::Create((irm http://company-server/bootstrap.ps1))) RunJob
```

<sup>`RunJob` is the OP's custom argument to pass to the script.</sup>

An **even shorter, but perhaps more obscure approach is to use `iex`**, the built-in alias for `Invoke-Expression`, courtesy of [this GitHub comment](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/8816#issuecomment-460349689).

```bash
iex "& { $(irm http://company-server/bootstrap.ps1) } RunJob"
```

<sup>As an aside: in general use, [Invoke-Expression should be avoided](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2011/06/03/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/).</sup>

The command uses an expandable string (`"..."`, string interpolation) to create a string with the remote script's *content* enclosed in a script block `{ ... }`, which is then invoked in a child scope (`&`). Note how the arguments to pass to the script must be *inside* `"..."`.

---

However, there is a **general caveat** (which doesn't seem to be a problem for you): **if the script terminates with `exit`, the *calling PowerShell instance is exited too***.

There are two **workarounds**:

---

**Run the script in a *child process*:**

```bash
powershell { iex "& { $(irm http://company-server/bootstrap.ps1) } RunJob" }
```

Caveats:

- The above only works from within PowerShell; from outside of PowerShell, you must use `powershell -c "..."` instead of `powershell { ... }`, but note that properly escaping *embedded* double quotes, if needed (for a URL with PS metacharacters and/or custom arguments with, say, spaces), can get tricky.
- If the script is designed to modify the caller's environment, the modifications will be lost due to running in a child process.

---

**Save the script to a *temporary file* first:**

Note: The command is spread across multiple lines for readability, but it also works as a one-liner:

```bash
& {
  $f = Join-Path ([IO.Path]::GetTempPath()) ([IO.Path]::GetRandomFileName() + '.ps1'); 
  irm http://company-server/bootstrap.ps1 > $f;
  & $f RunJob;
  ri $f
}
```

The obvious down-side is that the command is much longer.

Note that the command is written with robustness and cross-platform compatibility in mind, so that it also works in PowerShell *Core*, on all supported platforms.
Depending on what platforms you need to support / what assumptions you're willing to make (e.g., that the current dir. is writeable), the command can be shortened.

---

#### Potential future enhancements

[GitHub issue #5909](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5909#issuecomment-461192202), written as of PowerShell Core 6.2.0-preview.4 and revised as of PowerShell Core 7.0, proposes enhancing the 
`Invoke-Command` (`icm`) cmdlet to greatly simplify download-script-and-execute scenarios, so that you could invoke the script in question as follows:

```bash
# WISHFUL THINKING as of PowerShell Core 7.0
# iwr is the built-in alias for Invoke-WebRequest
# icm is the built-in alias for Invoke-Command.
iwr http://company-server/bootstrap.ps1 | icm -Args RunJob
```

[GitHub issue #8835](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/8835) goes even further, suggesting an RFC be created to introduce a new PowerShell *provider* that allows URLs to be used in places where only files were previously accepted, enabling calls such as:

```bash
# WISHFUL THINKING as of PowerShell Core 7.0
& http://company-server/bootstrap.ps1 RunJob
```

However, while these options are very convenient, there are *security implications* to consider.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a shorter solution (158 chars.)

```
$C=(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString("http://company-server/bootstrap.ps1");icm -ScriptBlock ([Scriptblock]::Create($c)) -ArgumentList "RunJob"
```

Here is 121

```
$C=(curl http://company-server/bootstrap.ps1).content;icm -ScriptBlock ([Scriptblock]::Create($c)) -ArgumentList "RunJob"
```

Here is 108

```
$C=(curl http://company-server/bootstrap.ps1).content;icm ([Scriptblock]::Create($c)) -ArgumentList "RunJob"
```

Here is 98

```
$C=(iwr http://company-server/bootstrap.ps1).content;icm -sc([Scriptblock]::Create($c)) -ar RunJob
```

Thanks to Ansgar Wiechers